# Autocomplete Dropdown in mvc4?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

Hi I have one field called **CustomerName** it is drop down. I want to make this field as Autocomplete drop down instead of selecting the value . But i can't get any idea to do this task . i am getting lot of confusions  so please any one help me to solve this issue

**My Controller code**

```
public JsonResult GetCustomers()
{
    return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**My View Code**

```
@Html.Label("Customer Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a Customer", new { @class = "form-control required", type = "text" })
```

**My J-query Code**

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax(
        '@Url.Action("GetCustomers", "VisitorsForm")',{
         type: "GET",
         datatype: "Json",
         success: function (data) {
             $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                 $('#CustomerID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerID + '">' + value.DisplayName + '</option>');
             });
         }
    });
});
```

This is my code it will load the CustomerName  in CustomerName Field from Db.it is perfectly working . But i want to make this field as Autocomplete Dropdown.I tried many ways but no use no one is working for this task. Please any one help me to complete this Autocomplete dropdown task.

Advance Thanks..

Comment: You need to us a jquery plugin - e.g. [jquery-ui autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) (and remove `type = "text"` from your `DropDownListFor()` method - its a `<select>` element, not an `<input>`)

Answer (score 0):

why are you giving type = "text" for a dropdown.
Actually you need to use jquery-autocomplete .
Follow the tutorial:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_autocomplete.htm